Twilio Transcribe audio call Google Speech To Text
I'm trying to transcribe audio to text using Google Speech to Text using Python. For this, I'm using the WebSocket stream to receive the audio.
@app.route("/receive_call", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_call():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        xml = f"""
<Response>
    <Say>
        Speak to see your speech transcribed in the console
    </Say>
    <Connect>
        <Stream url='wss://{request.host}{WEBSOCKET_ROUTE}' />
    </Connect>
</Response>
""".strip()

        return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')
    else:
        return f"Real-time phone call transcription app"

Here the websocket Code:
@sock.route(WEBSOCKET_ROUTE)
def transcription_websocket(ws):
    # audio_generator(ws)
    while True:

        data = json.loads(ws.receive())
        match data['event']:
            case "connected":
                transcriber = TwilioTranscriber()
                transcriber.connect()
                print('transcriber connected')
            case "start":
                print('twilio started')
            case "media":
                payload_b64 = data['media']['payload']
                chunk = base64.b64decode(payload_b64)
                transcribe=transcribe_audio(chunk)
                print(transcribe) 


The above value is returned as None.
So far, I have tried to transcribe the audio using Google Speech to Text API. I Tried with the MULAW or Linear encoding but got None as output.
Tried with:
**Encoding **  : MULAW or Linear16
sample rate: 8000 or 16000
None of the above is working.
def transcribe_audio(audio_content):
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=audio_content)
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding="MULAW",
        sample_rate_hertz=8000,
        language_code="en-US" )

    response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
    for result in response.results:
        return result.alternatives[0].transcript


Note: Using Ngrok to run the websocket locally

MULAW with a sample rate of 8000 is definitely the right choice. I'm not a python expert and it seems your snippets are missing some parts to understand this in more depth. But I'd recommend reading this post which does exactly what you want to do but with Nodejs. Maybe it helps you to debug
